# Print SQL Statement for Drupal 7 entities

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can i print the sql statement for

````
   $entities = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', "page")
    ->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid)
    ->fieldCondition('field_item_r1', 'value', $title)
    ->addTag('debug')->execute();```

Please help me to print the sql statement
````

Comment: The `devel` module must be enabled for the 'debug' tag to work. You can also try with `(string) $query` @see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2902311.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(string) $query` (I prefer this method if possible) or add `->addTag('debug')`.